# finding orthogonal vectors of a cylinder

Tags: math

Given r and h of a circular cylinder and two end points of h are A(x1,y1,z1) and B(x2,y2,z2). So h will be one among the three orthogonal vectors of the cylinder then how to find the other two orthogonal vectors?

Comment: Round structures with perfect rotational symmetry have an infinite number of orthogonal vectors.

Comment: This question belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the cylinder axis vector is U = B - A = (x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1); divide by its magnitude and you get a vector u = U / |U| of unit length. That's the easy part.

The other two orthogonal vectors are arbitrary, and there are many ways of determining them. Here's an easy one:

1. Pick a random vector r1.
2. Compute the portion of r1 that is *not* in the direction of u: r2 = r1 - (r1 . u) u; this vector is perpendicular to u because r2 . u = r1 . u - (r1 . u)*(u.u) = 0
3. If the magnitude of r2 is small (say, less than 0.1), go back to step 1.
4. Compute v = r2 / |r2|. This has unit length and is perpendicular to u.
5. Compute w = u x v. This has unit length and is perpendicular to u and v.

In general, I don't think there is any way to deterministically avoid trying more than one vector that is perpendicular to u. If you wanted to use a fixed coordinate transform matrix M to generate r1 = Mu, there's always a chance that r1 is very close to u in direction. (and linear operations like swapping the x and y components of a vector, or computing x' = y, y' = -x, can be written as coordinate transforms.)